# Remove not needed cookies from the back end request on haproxy

Tags: haproxy

My back-end website is a very small IOT application. Sometimes when a request is send to the back-end server it returns a 404 because the header is to big. This is caused by the cookies  send to the server.

Is it possible to send only the needed cookie to the back-end server by rewriting the header on the Haproxy ?

I’m looking for something that rewrites the header for cookies from

```
sesion=xyz; othercookie=123
```

to

```
sesion=xyz
```

Comment: Which version of HAProxy (`haproxy -v`)?  The version may constrain which capabilities are available or preferred.

Comment: haproxy -v
A-Proxy version 1.5.18 2016/05/10
Copyright 2000-2016 Willy Tarreau <willy@haproxy.org>

Answer (score 1):

You can use `http-request replace-header` or `http-request replace-value` to manipulate the Cookie header for the values you need. This is available in haproxy since version 1.5.

Example from the haproxy documentation:

> http-request replace-header Cookie foo=([^;]*);(.*) foo=\1;ip=%bi;\2
>     applied to:
>
> Cookie: foo=foobar; expires=Tue, 14-Jun-2016 01:40:45 GMT;
>
> outputs:
>
> Cookie: foo=foobar;ip=192.168.1.20; expires=Tue, 14-Jun-2016 01:40:45 GMT;
>
> assuming the backend IP is 192.168.1.20

[haproxy http-request documentation](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request)